# Chinese/Japanese Characters getting Truncated in Adobe pdf Forms

Tags: forms, pdf, itext, adobe, multilingual

Native Language Characters are truncated when you start typing them or paste them in form fields using Adobe. If I open it on chrome, it works fine. Currently I am using iTextSharp to populate the data properly to the pdf form. But as soon as I click on the field, font changes and the data gets truncated. Screenshot is attached. 
Note: Javascripts from PDF are already removed.

**EDIT**: PDF is available on https://gofile.io/?c=6nO7ul
Test Characters: 汉字汉
[image: As can be seen in the image, all the other fields have complete text visibility but in focussed field, bottom half is truncated.]

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: @mkl kindly check the edited question

Comment: Essentially your form is designed for Western European languages only. Thus, any PDF processor filling in Chinese/Japanese characters has to use a font it brings along instead of the design. On my computer Adobe Reader uses *Adobe Ming Std Light*. This font apparently has character definitions which require more vertical space than the fonts the form has been designed for. To fix this, simply change the default appearance font size of all those fields from its current value 8 to probably 6. Alternatively use 0 which indicates to the PDF processor that it shall use the largest fitting size.